# What is another term for co-worker but for someone ranked higher?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a term for a director of a program (or anyone ranked higher) that I don't directly report to, but I've worked with on various committees?

Comment: a fellow worker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A senior or a senior colleague.
As per the [Cambridge dictionary definition of senior](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/senior) - high or higher in rank.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate word choice, given your explained relationship, is *colleague*. The Merriam-Webster Dictionary defines colleague.

> An associate or coworker typically in a profession or in a civil or ecclesiastical office and often of similar rank or state
>
> A fellow worker or professional

Therefore, colleague is appropriate as it may be used to describe nearly everyone within your professional circles, and it allows for that person to be of a different rank than your own. *Associate* is a synonym that comes to mind, but I would be wary of using that word. Associate can denote someone of lesser than or equal rank to you, and it could easily be construed as a professional discourtesy.

Comment: But colleague covers any relative rank- often similar as noted in your definition.  OP asks for a term specifically for those above you.